# Webscraping with R: How can I tidy my data?

Tags: r, web-scraping, text, data-cleaning

I'm building a web scraper for some News websites in Switzerland. After some trial & error and a lot of help from StackOverflow (thx everyone!), I've gotten to a point where I can get text data from all articles.

```
#packages instalieren

install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("dplyr")
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

#seite einlesen

apisrf<- read_xml('https://www.srf.ch/news/bnf/rss/1646')

urls_srf <- apisrf %>% html_nodes('link') %>% html_text()
zeit_srf <- apisrf %>% html_nodes('pubDate') %>% html_text()

#data.frame basteln

dfsrf_titel_text <- data.frame(Text = character())

#scrape

for(i in 1:length(urls_srf)) {
  link <- urls_srf[i]
  
  artikel <- read_html(link)
  
  #Informationen entnehmen
  textsrf<- artikel %>% html_nodes('p') %>% html_text()
 
  #In Dataframe strukturieren
  
  dfsrf_text <- data.frame(Text = textsrf)
  
  dfsrf_titel_text <- rbind(dfsrf_titel_text, cbind(dfsrf_text))  
       
}
```

running this gives me dfsrf_titel_text. (I'm going to combine it with the titles of the articles at some point but let that be my problem.)

however, now my data is pretty untidy and I can't really figure out how to clean it in a way so it works for me. Especially annoying is that the texts from the different articles are not really structured in that way but get a new line whenever there is a paragraph in the texts. I can't combine the paragraphs because all the texts have different lengths. (The first article, starting at point 3, is super long because it's a live ticker covering the corona crisis so don't get confused if you run my code.)

how can I get R to create a new row in my dataframe only if the text is from a new article (meaning from a new URL?

thx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correct this while creating dataframe itself. Here I am binding this all the data for each article together using `paste0` adding new line character between them (`\n\n`).

```
library(rvest)

for(i in 1:length(urls_srf)) {
    link <- urls_srf[i]
    artikel <- read_html(link)
    #Informationen entnehmen
    textsrf<- paste0(artikel %>% html_nodes('p') %>% html_text(), collapse = "\n\n")
    #In Dataframe strukturieren
    dfsrf_text <- data.frame(Text = textsrf)
    dfsrf_titel_text <- rbind(dfsrf_titel_text, cbind(dfsrf_text))  
}
```

---

However, growing data in a loop is highly inefficient and can slow the process terribly especially when you have large data to scrape like this. Try using `sapply`.

```
dfsrf_titel_text <- data.frame(text = sapply(urls_srf, function(x) {
    paste0(read_html(x) %>% html_nodes('p') %>% html_text(), collapse = "\n\n")
}))
```

So this will give you number of rows same as length of `urls_srf` .

Comment: there is one more thing I need help with: this code worked perfectly fine until today but now it says "Maximum (10) redirects followed". Is there a way to workaround the redirects?

Comment: I am not aware about dealing with redirects while webscraping. Maybe you can post a new question?

Answer (score 2):

can you provide a sample of your data? you can use the `strsplit(string, pattern)` function where the pattern you specify is something that only happens between articles. Perhaps the URL?

```
strsplit(dfsrf_text,"www.\\w+.ch")
```

That will split your text anytime a URL in the .ch domain is found. you can use [this regular expression cheat sheet](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) to help you identify the pattern that seperates your articles.